# Create vertex and edge list from PubMed articles author list

Tags: r, graph, igraph, pubmed

I am trying to build an R igraph graph by fetching articles from PubMed via the RISmed package by building a vertex list dataframe as follows:

```
Name              Count
Cardone L         22
...               ...
Sassone-Corsi P   6
...               ...
```

and a corresponding (undirected) edge list

```
V1        V2              NumberOfCoAuthorships
Cardone L Sassone-Corsi P 4
```

Here is the data I am fetching:

```
#install.packages("RISmed")
library(RISmed)
limit = 100
query = "Cardone L[AUTH]"
# build the Eutils object
search_query <- EUtilsSummary(query, type="esearch",db = "pubmed",mindate=1980, maxdate=2016, retmax=limit)
# now let's fetch authors
auths<-Author(EUtilsGet(search_query))
# to extract all the names in the LastName Initials format
Authors<-sapply(auths, function(x)paste(x$LastName,x$Initials))
```

but I am really not wrapping my head around on how to build the edges and vertexes dataframes for a future igraph graph object from the Authors list of strings

```
> head(Authors,3)
[[1]]
[1] "Cardone L"

[[2]]
 [1] "Carrella D"     "Manni I"        "Tumaini B"      "Dattilo R"      "Papaccio F"     "Mutarelli M"   
 [7] "Sirci F"        "Amoreo CA"      "Mottolese M"    "Iezzi M"        "Ciolli L"       "Aria V"        
[13] "Bosotti R"      "Isacchi A"      "Loreni F"       "Bardelli A"     "Avvedimento VE" "di Bernardo D" 
[19] "Cardone L"     

[[3]]
[1] "Ventre S"      "Indrieri A"    "Fracassi C"    "Franco B"      "Conte I"       "Cardone L"    
[7] "di Bernardo D"
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What graph are you trying to create? Do you just want the authors connected to "Cardone L" and their connections through his papers, or do you want to also look up all of these authors and everyone that they ever published with ... and everyone that they published with?

Comment: First graph I'd like to create is just the coauthorship between the Authors with the edges being undirected but weighted by the number of papers in which they cooperated. A second graph I'd like to construct in the future is one edge for every paper labeled with the year of the paper to show how current is the coolaboration between paper authors. Thank you!

Comment: HEY! :-) Just "discovered the combn function :-)
So a step forwards would be for example:

Comment: Oooops sorry previous comment interrupted by crying baby
...
So a step forwards would be for example:
combn(Authors[[21]],2,simplify = FALSE)
which would build a list of the 6 combinations of the 4 authors